# Java Multithreading - Thread always waiting

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running these two methods in two separate threads. For some reason, depending on what aval is initially set to, one or the other thread will always be wait()ing and never woken by the notifyAll() call from the other thread.

http://pastebin.com/2DT6BTH6

Comment: Have you declared aval as volatile ??

Comment: And not printing the error in catch block is not a good idea.. You always have to print...Atleast the stack trace..

Comment: Vaibhav G, Setting it to volatile yields the same result

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0):

You are passing different objects in Threads. Wait, notifyAll are always used on the same object. The object your thread is waiting on is different than the object on which notifyall is called.

Comment: I don't see how it is a slippedCondition. It seems to me that my code and his "not slippedConditon" code are very similar.

Comment: Can you add your main method too?

Comment: You are passing different objects in Threads. Wait, notifyAll are always used on the same object.

The object your thread is waiting on is different than the object on which notifyall is called.

Comment: I was under the assumption that notifyAll() will notify ALL threads to get out of wait state, regardless of which object the thread is on

Comment: Read more about this on :http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html#wait-notify